# I can not share video to whatsapp from my app

Tags: java, android, share, whatsapp

I have an Android Studio project with the option to share videos by whatsapp.

This is my code:

```
        private void shareFile(File file){
        String titulo = file.getName();
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        shareIntent.setType("video/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
```

But when I share it I receive the message from Whatsapp: this file format is not compatible.
I do not understand what happens, before it worked.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` has been banned on Android 7.0+. Use `FileProvider`. Also, use a real MIME type, not a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>

</provider>
```

FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS.XML in res/xml

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name=”files” path=”/” />
</paths>
```

USE YOUR FILEPROVIDER

```
// create new Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// set flag to give temporary permission to external app to use your FileProvider
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// generate URI, I defined authority as the application ID in the Manifest, the last param is file I want to open
String uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);

// I am opening a PDF file so I give it a valid MIME type
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

// validate that the device can open your File!
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It works with the files in the internal memory of the phone but with files in the removable volume I receive the following error: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/0000-0000/file.mp4